# is there a way to access the validation rules for a spreadsheet range in google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have looked at the documentation for Spreadsheet class, Sheet class, and Range class.
I can not find a method that would give access to a range's validation rule(s).

And I looked in the documentation "using validation rules".

Is it possible to access the attribute(s), for each cell in a range?

I also assume that each cell in a range can only have one validation rule. 
Am I wrong in this assumption?
I arrived at this assumption, because a cell appears to only display a single validation message.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18426412/1677912) that uses the recently-released validation API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps Script doesn't currently provide a way to access validation rules. There is a feature request open that you can follow though: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=219.

Comment: It's been released (I haven't tried it). https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation