# How to set and keep a validation rule on all cells in a column of a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets

Is there a way to set and keep a validation rule on every cell in a spreadsheets row, even when user inserts or appends a new row?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18426412/1677912) that uses the recently-released validation API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same question but at last found a solution this might be option for you problem ->for this i had used a script based on onEdit event and check the total number rows every time if there found more than the required columns then copy with formatting is applied to all the rows and columns in the sheet. So that it ensures that all the rows has the formatting.

You can try this if there is no alternatives.
Best of luck.