# How can I set validation through a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a list range to validate the data in a column. How can I set this validation through a script?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [`Range.setDataValidations(dataValidation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setDataValidations%28DataValidation%29).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18426412/1677912) that uses the recently-released validation API calls.